# In the given line, what is the relation between ‘short-sighted’ and ‘education’? What does it mean by strict views on education?

Tags: meaning, oscar-wilde, the-importance-of-being-earnest

In Act II of *The Importance of Being Earnest*, Gwendolen says this in a conversation with Cecily:

> Gwendolen: [...] And certainly once a man begins to neglect his domestic duties he becomes painfully effeminate, does he not? And I don't like that. It makes man so very attractive. Cecily, **mamma, whose views on education are remarkably strict, has brought me up to be extremely short-sighted; it is part of her system** [...]

What is this line's meaning and is Gwendolen insulting her mother?

Comment: Traditionally people thought that myopia (short-sightedness, nearsightedness) was brought on by too much close work such as reading. [Recent research](https://nei.nih.gov/health/errors/myopia) seems to indicate that it's caused by spending too much time indoors, but of course Oscar Wilde or his characters wouldn't know about that. It's easy to imagine how a strict system of education might result in a child spending too much time indoors, reading. From the quoted lines it appears that Gwendolyn may not share or appreciate her mother's views on education. I don't see an insult here.

Comment: I believe the word *short-sighted* is being used in the literal sense of "Having short sight; having the focus of the eyes at less than the normal distance; unable to distinguish objects clearly at a distance; myopic" (OED) rather than any figurative sense, especially in view of the part of the quotation you omitted at the end: "Cecily, mamma, whose views on education are remarkably strict, has brought me up to be extremely short-sighted; it is part of her system; **so do you mind my looking at you through my glasses?**"